# Getting results from a trigger to php where INSERT is the condition of triggering the trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get result/table using insert statement but not select statement.

My attempt is to use a trigger that will Select * From Table after each Insert Statements.My theory is that I can use insert to display the table instead of select since I got a select statement to be executed after insert.

But somehow, there's an error such as "Trying to get property of non-object"

Below is my code:

```
$insert = "insert into algtable values ('1', 'adventure'), ('1', 'adventure'), ('1', 'adventure');";
$result = $conn->query($insert);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "<table><tr><th>UserID</th><th>Total</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr><td name = 'UID'>".$row["UserID"]."</td><td rowname = 'totalcount'>".$row["Total"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET('totalcount'));
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

And below is my trigger statement:

```
create trigger trgselaftins on algtable 
after insert 
as 
select UserID, Count(Genre) as Total 
from algtable 
where UserID = 1 AND Genre = 'adventure' group by UserID
```

I have been looking here and there for solutions, but none of them works. Therefore I'm trying to ask a question by myself here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `num_rows()` on INSERT? you're looking to use `affected_rows()`. As does `fetch_assoc()` which works with SELECT, not INSERT.

Comment: That I'm well aware, but I thought that all these are going to execute the query and get the table output. And since I got a trigger created that will SELECT the table after INSERT, shouldn't it be doing just the same? But thanks for the suggestion anyway, appreciated it.

Comment: check your logs, you'll see what I mean. If you don't have access to logs, then use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php that should be throwing you syntax errors.

Comment: Unless this is just an exercise, I think it would be better to simply use a separate SELECT query, rather than try to use a trigger to do a select. It would be more clear to anyone else who is reading the code what it's doing, and you won't have to fool PHP into expecting a result set from an INSERT statement.

Comment: True, sometimes after I'm struggling with this, I've found out that with or without trigger, I'm still doing the stuff in almost the same number of steps, using insert then select and insert then insert again.